# vectorize index lookup in pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy, vectorization

I'm looping thru a dataset trying to find values in an index.  If the value isn't in the (multi-level) index, then I take a default value:

```
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if i in avg_days.index:
        df.at[i,'avg_days_to_n'] = round(avg_days.xs(i,axis=0)[1],0)
    else:
        df.at[i,'avg_days_to_n'] = round(avg_days.xs((i[0],i[1]),level (0,1),drop_level=False).avg_days_between_n.mean(),0)
```

is there a way to vectorize this?

Here is what the avg_days dataframe looks like:

```
                            avg_n
state   project_type    cat 
FL      R               Hur 33
CA      C               EE  43
```

Here is what df looks like:

```
                            id
state   project_type    cat 
FL      R               Hur abc-1
CA      C               EE  def-2
```

So, for each row in df, if the index state-project_type-cat has an index match in avg_days, I return the avg_n value.

If not, i "move up" the index and take the state-project type (and NOT cat) value as i know that will return something

Comment: "is there a way to vectorize this?" Yes. How? I don't know, you haven't given me any data or [mcve] to work with.

Comment: @coldspeed.  you are right, now with data

Comment: adding the indices to your dataframes would help a lot

Comment: @pythonic833 the indicies are there. for avg_days it's state-project_type and cat.  for df it is the same things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part, matching all 3 indexes at the same time can be easily achieved with the [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html#pandas.merge) function, which is implemented in pandas. In order to maintain all the indexes found in `df` even when they are not present in `avg_days`, the `how` argument must be set to `left`:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df,avg_days,right_index=True,left_index=True,how='left')
```

The second part is trickier than that. After the merge, there will be indexes without any value in the `avg_n` value of the `merged_df` dataframe, which will be the ones that have to be set to the `avg_n` mean of the first 2 indexes.

The mean values can be calculated with the groupby function, and then the indexes of the list that need to be corrected can be obtained checking for `NaN`.

```
days_grouped = np.around(avg_days.groupby(['state','project_type']).mean())
nan_mask = ~np.isfinite(merged_df['avg_n'])
indexes2correct = [(s,p) for s,p,c in merged_df[nan_mask].index.values]
```

Finally, the rows containing `NaN` can be updated using the values in `days_gruped`:

```
merged_df.loc[nan_mask,'avg_n'] = days_grouped.loc[indexes2correct]['avg_n'].values
```

**Note**: I compared the results obtained with the code shown in the question and this way of vectorizing, and there are some differences that should be taken into account:

- Here, only the means are rounded, and the values in `avg_days['avg_n']` are assumed to be integers already.
- The rounding is done with `numpy.round` instead of the built-in `round`, which in some cases round to different values (see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617841/rounding-to-nearest-int-with-numpy-rint-not-consistent-for-5) for more information).